# Open up MySQL, Redis etc. only to certain other servers?

Tags: mysql, bind, redis

Many server applications like MySQL or Redis are by default only accessible by localhost, having a config line like `bind 127.0.0.1`. If you want to connect remotely, you have to remove this line.

Now, if I remove this line, theoretically every computer could try to connect here. Can I somehow configure the server to only accept connections to these services from a given list of other servers? This way I want to make sure that my other servers can access it, while random computers can't. It's worth pointing out that my other server are not all in the same network, so connections have to be over the internet.

Perfect solution would be if I could set it to only allow connections from a certain RDNS (like *.domain.com), so I wouldn't have to reconfigure this for every new server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I somehow configure the server to only accept connections to these services from a given list of other servers?

Yes, that is called a [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)). There you configure white-listed ip-addresses and/or ranges of ip-addresses that are allowed access to services on your server.

> Perfect solution would be if I could set it to only allow connections from a certain RDNS (like `*.example.com`), so I wouldn't have to reconfigure this for every new server.

Please don't do that (even if you could technically) because although that sounds convenient it is not secure. The owner of an ip-address can set any hostname name they want on a reverse DNS record, including one from domains that they don't own such as yours...

Answer (score 1):

> Many server applications like MySQL or Redis are by default only accessible by localhost, having a config line like bind `127.0.0.1`. If you want to connect remotely, you have to remove this line.

If you want to connect remotely, You can bind the server to the specific IP address on which you want the service to listen. There is no need to remove this line. Let's say

```
 bind address 192.168.0.1      #### Private Binding
 bind address 52.14.133.10     #### public Binding
```

But this solution will work only if you want to bind only one server. For multiple listening  the solution suggested above i.e **firewall** is the only solution.